# Pressing ctrl-c with multiple processes piping their stdout into a single process kills the shell

Tags: shell, zsh

I have a script which executes multiple http requests in parallel and allows the user to search the results:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

function swapiperson() {
  curl -sL "https://swapi.co/api/people/$1" |  jq -r '.name'
}

function fzfpeople() {
  set -e

  person=$({for ((req=0;req<10;req++)); do
    swapiperson $req &
  done} | fzf --no-hscroll +m)

  [ ${#person} -gt 0 ] && echo $person
}
```

This script requires `curl`, `jq`, and `fzf` to be installed. If you execute `fzfpeople` and then press `ctrl-c` without selecting an option the parent `zsh` process will die and the terminal emulator will close. I know the problem isn't `fzf` because my other `fzf` scripts do not do this and because if I replace `fzf` with `less` I see the same problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

function swapiperson() {
  curl -sL "https://swapi.co/api/people/$1" |  jq -r '.name'
}

function lesspeople() {
  set -e

  {for ((req=0;req<10;req++)); do
    swapiperson $req &
  done} | less
}
```

Run `lesspeople`, press `ctrl-c`, and the shell exits. This indicates to me that there is some problem with the way I am running the parallel requests and piping them all together. Are there any simple solutions for the problem I am seeing? I need to be able to combine the `stdout`s of multiple parallel requests and pipe them into `fzf`.

Comment: What do you want to happen when you send an interrupt signal to your script?

Comment: I just want to go back to the shell. Basically I have a search script and sometimes I want to exit without choosing an option but continue using other commands in the same shell. The shell being killed off is rather annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was embarassingly simple. I just had to remove `set -e` from `lesspeople` and `fzfpeople` respectively. Here are the proper, working code listings:

`fzfpeople.zsh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

function swapiperson() {
  curl -sL "https://swapi.co/api/people/$1" |  jq -r '.name'
}

function fzfpeople() {
  person=$({for ((req=0;req<10;req++)); do
    swapiperson $req &
  done} | fzf --no-hscroll +m)

  [ ${#person} -gt 0 ] && echo $person
}
```

`lesspeople.zsh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

function swapiperson() {
  curl -sL "https://swapi.co/api/people/$1" |  jq -r '.name'
}

function lesspeople() {
  {for ((req=0;req<10;req++)); do
    swapiperson $req &
  done} | less
}
```